# different colors to each row in a form in extjs

Tags: extjs

How to give different colors to each row in a form in extjs? I used cls:'class name in style' inside every field. In the css class I defined the background color. But that color is coming for label only. After the textfield the background color is not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the fieldStyle:

```
fieldStyle: 'background-color: #ddd; background-image: none;'
```

Comment: I already tried but it is giving color for only the fields like textbox. I want to give color to label as well as the spaces after the textbox.